# In jannah could i create my own world? Or enter a world from like a cartoon show? Even go back in time?

Tags: jannah

I was really curious if i could just enter some of my favorite shows and be one of the characters and live through it and also go back in time? What i mean by going back in time i mean like not actually going to the real world but my own real world?

Answer (score 4):

Allah and His Holy Prophet (Peace Be Upon Him) introduced the Jannah as a place where any wish will be fulfilled. This explanation has such an absoluteness, that there remains no need left to explain it further. See Quran verse 31,32 of Chapter 41 (Surah Ha-Meem Assajdah, Ayat 31 & 32)

> Those who say 'Allah is our Lord' and then remain steadfast, upon them descend angels (and say): Do not fear nor grieve and receive good tidings of the Jannah which you were promised. We are your companions in this world and the Hereafter; there you shall have all that you desire and what you will ask for.

So considering this promise by our Lord Allah (SWT), you shall have if you desire for this in Jannah.

However, there is another aspect of the story, which remains. There are many things, which we extremely desire at one point of time in our age but later, when we grow in wisdom and know things more, that desire may be turned out to be meaningless. For example, a two or three-year kid may extraordinarily desire to collect plenty of colorful balloons so that other fellow kids may admire them. However, at the age of 40, or 50, the same kid may not be interested anymore in that childish wish. So it can also be possible that the wish you are currently making may be turned out to be a childish meaningless wish in Jannah considering the level of fun and enjoyment available there. But, still, InShaAllah, you will be given whatever you wish there. So try your best to reach there and then what we say today is, the world will be in your hand.